# Android- ActionBar lcon padding with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to create a ActionBar like WhatsApp one, with the picture of the user as a Icon of the Activity. 
The problem that I have is that the ActionBar shows the picture too small.
I know how to solve this with a Custom Layout for ActionBar, but when I use it together with a Navigation Drawer (ActionBarDrawerToogle) it automatically put the Drawer indicator + AppIcon too.

How can I put just the Drawer indicator and set the Icon as a ImageView from my CustomLayout or change the default padding of the Icon in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to get `ImageView` reference from android.R.id.home and change the scale type? Or just change margins different from `action_bar_icon_vertical_padding`

Comment: I tried this: 'ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);' but seems that 0,0,0,0 is the default already. I can only increase the default value, not decrease

Comment: How can i try with action_bar_icon_vertical_padding?
Where I can change this value?

Comment: Margins is not the same as padding. Use setMargins

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically : 
((ImageView) android.R.id.home).setPadding(7,0,7,0)
[Sample](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/04/solution-actionbar-space-or-padding.html)